# Why is the degeneracy in the eigenvalue representation of eigenkets always lifted when using a maximal set of commuting observables?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, commutator, observables

I don't see how this implicit theorem Sakurai states in his book on QM on page 31 can be proven in general

> Assume that we have found a maximal set of commuting observables; that is, we cannot add any more observables to our list without violating 
>   $$[A,B]=[B,C]=[A,C]=...=0$$
>   The eigenvalues of individual operators A,B,C,... may have degeneracies but if we specify a combination $|a',b',c',...\rangle$. The corresponding simultaneous eigenket of $A,B,C,...$ is uniquely specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like all proofs about properties of "maximal" sets in any context, this one too proceeds by assuming that we have a set that lacks the property and then constructing something we can add to the set, showing it was not maximal:

Assume we have a set of $n$ operators $A_i$ and that there is a degenerate common eigenvector, i.e. an (w.l.o.g.) two -dimensional eigenspace spanned by vectors $\lvert a_1,\dots,a_n\rangle_1$ and $\lvert a_1,\dots,a_n\rangle_2$ that have the same eigenvectors for the set.

Then the operator $A_{n+1}$ that acts on vectors outside this space just like $A_1$, but on these two vectors as $A_{n+1}\lvert a_1,\dots,a_n\rangle_1 = \lvert a_1,\dots,a_n\rangle_1$ and $A_{n+1}\lvert a_1,\dots,a_n\rangle_2 = -\lvert a_1,\dots,a_n\rangle_2$ commutes with all the $A_i$ (because it is diagonal in their common eigenbasis) and lifts the degeneracy, so the set of $A_i$ was not maximal.

Answer (score 1):

A physical way to think about this is that, if you have a degeneracy then you have a symmetry. Namely, if $|1\rangle,|2\rangle$ are states with the same set of eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ under $A_1,\ldots,A_n$, then there exists an operator that rotates $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ into each other and leaves all other observables untouched
$$
U(\theta)\left(\begin{matrix}|1\rangle\\|2\rangle\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}\cos\theta |1\rangle +\sin\theta|2\rangle \\\cos\theta|2\rangle -\sin\theta|1\rangle\end{matrix}\right)\,.
$$
You can say that this is a symmetry because, for any state
$$
A_n \,U(\theta)|\psi\rangle =  \lambda_n\,U(\theta)|\psi\rangle\,,
$$
that is, the eigenvalues are not changed. But then, if you look at the equation above, that's just saying that $U$ and $A_n$ commute.

---

This is no different from @ACuriousMind♦ answer. I just wanted to emphasize that "degeneracy" should sound like "symmetry" in your head.