# Maximality and Completeness for Set of Compatible Observables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, commutator

Let $\mathcal{A} = \{A_j\}_{j=1}^{N}$ be a finite family of compatible observables (they commute pairwise) on an Hilbert space $H$. Consider the following definitions:

> $\mathcal{A}$ is **Maximal** if and only if, by adjoining a new observable $B$, if the observables are still commuting, then $B$ is a function of $\{A_j\}_{j=1}^{N}$ (I am referring to Valter Moretti's answer to the following question: [Proof of the set of compatible observable have a bound](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/631759/)).

> $\mathcal{A}$ is **Complete** if and only if, for any choice of $\{a_j\}_{j=1}^{N}$ eigenvalues of $\{A_j\}_{j=1}^{N}$ respectively, $\cap_{j=1}^{N} Eig(a_j)$ is a one-dimensional Hilbert subspace of $H$ ($Eig(a_j)$ denotes the eigenspace of $A_j$ relative to $a_j$).

I would like to know wether this two notions are equivalent or not and in the former case if there is a Proof of the claim.

I would also like to point out that, despite the fact that the question seems to be partially solved by ACuriousMind's answer ([Why is the degeneracy in the eigenvalue representation of eigenkets always lifted when using a maximal set of commuting observables?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/541448/)), in reality the notion of maximality there is different (it only requires that we can not adjoin another operator and preserve commutativity) and actually undermines the question itself because even in a finite-dimensional Hilbert space a maximal set of commuting observables may contain infinitely many members according to this definition (e.g.: if the set contains a non-null operator $A$ then it must include $\{nA\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$).